# Batch job submission failed: I/O error writing script/environment to file

Tags: jobs, slurm, submission, sbatch

I installed slurm on a workstation and it seemed to work, i can use the slurm commands, srun is working too.
But when i try to launch a job from a script using `sbatch test.sh` i get the following error : **Batch job submission failed: I/O error writing script/environment to file** even if the script is the simplest like
`#!/bin/bash`
`srun hostname`

Comment: Is `slurmd` running as root?

Comment: yes it is running as root

Comment: Slurm seems to complain it cannot write to the location defined by `SlurmdSpoolDir`. Could be a faulty or read-only filesystem?

Comment: Yes it turned out it was a permission problem, i had the rw permission for root user but in my conf file user was set to slurm. I changed it to root and it worked.

Comment: Was this the `SlurmUser` or `SlurmdUser` that you set to root to get things to work again?

Comment: In my case it just happens from time to time and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `slurmd` is running as `root`. See the `SlurmdUser` parameter in `slurm.conf`. Its default value is `root` and it should be so.

Note this is different from the `SlurmUser` parameter, that defines the user which runs the controller processes ; this one is preferably not `root`.

If the configuration is correct, then you might have a faulty filesystem at the location referred to in the `SlurmdSpoolDir` parameter, where `slurmd` writes the submission script and environment for jobs assigned to the node.